# Install Mycrypt on Centos 6.5

Tags: php, centos

I need to install **Mycrypt** in order to run `php artisan serve` on my Centos 6.5. So, I added the EPEL by the following commands

```
rpm -ivh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
yum install php-mcrypt
```

However, when I run the yum install, the output is like this

```
Error: php55w-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I don't know what to do at this point. Please help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests, it's conflicted.  Your current install version of PHP differs from the one you're trying to install.

Maybe you're trying to install a 5.3 version against a 5.5.  Look to find a matching version.

It's also possible you should to a "yum update" prior to installing the mcrypt RPM.

I found this from: http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/installing-rhel-epel-repo-on-centos-5x-or-6x

```
wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
sudo rpm -Uvh remi-release-6*.rpm epel-release-6*.rpm
```

It would help to know what version of PHP you are currently running.  The mcrypt on the epel is php-mcrypt-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64.rpm.   Usually you can find out the version by either php -v on the command line, or phpinfo() in one of your scripts.

Comment: yeah I updated yum and re-run the command but no luck.

and what do you mean by "Look to find a matching version"?

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?  Usually you can find out the version by either php -v on the command line, or phpinfo() in one of your scripts.

Comment: yeah, it is PHP 5.5.11